# Terraform ignores values in .tfvars?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm trying to add clustering to BigQuery with Terraform with the values coming from .tfvars.

**main.tf**:

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "database" {
  for_each                   = { for k, v in var.dbs : k => v }
  dataset_id                 = each.value.db_id
  friendly_name              = each.value.db_name
  description                = "Dataset created by Terraform"
  location                   = "US"
  delete_contents_on_destroy = var.delete_contents_on_destroy
  labels                     = each.value.labels
}

module "tables" {
  source   = "./tables"
  for_each = { for k, v in var.dbs : k => v }
  db_id    = google_bigquery_dataset.database[each.key].dataset_id
  labels   = each.value.labels
  tables   = each.value.tables
}
```

**variables.tf:**

```
variable "dbs" {
  type = list(object({
    db_id   = string
    db_name = string
    labels  = map(string)
    tables = list(object({
      id          = string
      partitioned = string
      field       = string
      type        = string
      clustering  = list(string)
    }))

  }))
}
```

**./tables/tables.tf** (module):

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "tables" {
  for_each = {
    for m in var.tables : "${m.id}" => m
  }
  dataset_id          = var.db_id
  deletion_protection = false
  table_id            = each.value.id
  clustering = try(each.value.clustering, [])

  dynamic "time_partitioning" {
    for_each = each.value.partitioned == "true" ? [1] : []
    content {
      type  = each.value.type
      field = each.value.field
    }
  }

  labels = var.labels
  schema = fileexists("${path.module}/${var.db_id}/${each.value.id}.json") ? file("${path.module}/${var.db_id}/${each.value.id}.json") : null
}
```

**dev.tfvars:**

```
dbs = [
  {
    db_id   = "some_db"
    db_name = "some_db"
    labels = {
      environment = "development"
    }
    tables = [
      {
        id          = "daily_inventory"
        partitioned = "true"
        field       = "inventory_timestamp"
        type        = "DAY"
      },
      {
        id          = "daily_sales"
        partitioned = "true"
        field       = "sales_timestamp"
        type        = "DAY"
        clustering = ["store_identifier", "product_identifier"]
      },
      {
        id          = "stores"
        partitioned = "false"
        field       = ""
        type        = ""
      }
]
```

When I run terraform plan, terraform says:

> "No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration."

and completely ignores

```
clustering = ["store_identifier", "product_identifier"]
```

If I set the clustering field directly in the module then terraform recognizes the changes and wants to add the clustering for the columns properly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you execute `terraform` command exactly?

Comment: terraform runs using a Jenkins pipeline but to simplify: terraform apply -var-file=dev.tfvars -upgrade -input=false

Comment: also added variables.tf to the post so you can see the data structure @Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work, beacuse in your code, `clustering = try(each.value.clustering, [])` is determined by `var.tables`. However, you are changing `var.dbs`, not `var.tables`.

Comment: Hey Marcin, thanks as always but not sure I follow. in my child module I exported the "tables" variable to the root module. In the main.tf I am referring to "tables" as "each.value.tables" which is an attribute inside the "dbs" variable. How come in works with "each.value.partitioned"? What am I missing?

Comment: Also, on terraform plan, I see that it wants to add clustering = [] to all tables that have no values for each.value.clustering.